# Scala: Generic integer return type?

Tags: scala, generics

I'm new to Scala. 
I have a function:

```
def fromBinaryListBig(in: Array[Int]): BigInt = {
  var sum = 0
  in foreach (x => {sum <<= 1; sum += (x&1)})
  sum
}
```

Is it possible to make the return type generic (integer types, Long, Int)?
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2):

You can have a generic return type if it matches a generic parameter ...

```
def fromBinaryListBig[N:Numeric](in: Array[N]): N = in.sum
```

... but you can't get different (generic) return types based on some internal condition (such as the value of an accumulated sum, for example).

Comment: Thx for the reply. Is it possible to to make "sum" also generic? I would like to avoid copying the same code over and over again but change only the return type.

Comment: @paul Numeric has a sum function

Comment: @paul, I've changed the example to return the sum of an `Array` of any numeric type. The return type matches the `Array` type. If the sum value is likely to overflow the input type then you need to go with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, it's quite possible:

```
def fromBinaryListBig[A](in: Array[Int])(implicit ev: Integral[A]): A = {
  var sum = ev.zero
  val two = ev.fromInt(2)
  in foreach (x => {sum *= two; sum += ev.fromInt(x&1)})
  sum
}
```

This means the caller determines the return type, so they can write e.g.

```
val x = fromBinaryListBig[Byte](Array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

or specify the expected type

```
val x: BigInt = fromBinaryListBig(...)
```